# label_binarize Does not fit for sklearn Naive Bayes classifier showing bad input shape

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

I was trying to create roc curve for multiclass using Naive Bayes But it ending with

> ValueError: bad input shape.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

from scipy import interp

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

# Add noisy features to make the problem harder
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# shuffle and split training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5,
                                                    random_state=0)

# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = BernoulliNB(alpha=1.0, binarize=6, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

> raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
>
> ValueError: bad input shape (75, 6)

Comment: Which line? And why six classes, Iris has only three?!?

Comment: on last line where i tried to fit the classifier.
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
I even tried with 3 class but i'm getting error.

Answer (score 0):

The error because of binarizing the `y` variable. The estimator can work with string values itself.

Remove the following lines,

```
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]
```

You are good to go!

To get the predicted probabilities for `roc_curve`, use the following:

```py
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
y_score.shape
# (75, 3)
```